# How to write file contents as seen in debug mode?

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io, output

I'd like to write the contents of a file as seen when I hover over the StreamReader object of the file, ie, Content\t\tOtherContent\t\t\t\t

When i try the code below, I just get the full file contents without the codes as I want:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(f);

            using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\test.txt"))
            {
                CopyStream(reader.BaseStream, file);
            }

 public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
```

Again, I'd like output like this in this file:
**Content\t\tOtherContent\t\t\t\t**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
Regex.Escape(reader.ReadToEnd());
```